# How to get my business opened hours with google-maps-api?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I am looking to use google maps api which can return me business hours if I provide the business PlaceID. Can someone point me in right direction ?

I searched there but didnt find the exact right way https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You will need a place details request to return business hours. Please see documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details

You can do something like this to get weekday hours for a certain day:

```
place.opening_hours.weekday_text[0]
```

Where you can enter 0-6 for each day of the week

I have a simple JSFiddle showing how this can be done. Please see here:

https://jsfiddle.net/k3w22wsy/

Please note that you will need to supply an API key in order for the fiddle to work. Replace 'MY_API_KEY' with an API key you own and you will be able to use this sample.

I hope this helps!